# Как вывести матрицу коэффициентов

Tags: python

Есть практические задания по машинному обучению. В результате прохождения заданий мы получаем обученную модель. Все уже решено. Но мне необходимо в конце, как я понял, когда модель уже обучена всему, что только возможно, вывести матрицу коэффициентов. Я так понимаю надо использовать каким-то образом **.corr()**. Но как именно, я так и не понял.

```
#подготовим данные для обучения и теста
tmp_scaled = StandardScaler().fit_transform(full_new_feat[['start_month', 
'start_hour', 'morning']])

X_train = csr_matrix(hstack([full_sites_sparse[:idx_split,:], 
                         tmp_scaled[:idx_split,:]]))

X_test = csr_matrix(hstack([full_sites_sparse[idx_split:,:], 
                        tmp_scaled[idx_split:,:]]))

#обучим модель на всей выборке с оптимальным коэффициентом регуляризации

lr = LogisticRegression(C=C, random_state=17).fit(X_train, y_train)

#сделаем прогноз для тестовой выборки
y_test = lr.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]

#запишем его в файл, готовый для сабмита
write_to_submission_file(y_test, 'baseline_2.csv')

y_test
```

[Вот ссылка на файл с ЯД.](https://yadi.sk/d/abHHZjvy3QFXjR) Файл .ipynb - это файл **jupyter notebook**

Answer (score 0):

Коэффициенты можно увидеть вот так:

```
lr.coef_
```

Правда это уже должны были давно рассказать в рамках этой специализации на Coursera.